# Route SOAP request through external server

Tags: proxy

I need to integrate with a SOAP Web Service that requires that the requests come from a whitelisted IP address.

As I often do development from all over the place it is quite annoying to ask for a new whitelisted IP each time.

I have a remote server that is whitelisted.  How can I route my SOAP request (I can change the endpoint in the WSDL) to my remote machine and have that forwarded to the Web Service?

My remote server is used for other things so it needs to only forward a specific port, not all traffic.

Oh, and the Web Service expects SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing [tinyproxy](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tinyproxy) on the whitelisted machine

`sudo apt-get install tinyproxy`

Then I added my computer's external IP address to the config at `/etc/tinyproxy.conf` as only local host was allowed to proxy by default.

Finally, I set the [PHP SOAP client](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) to point to the proxy:

`$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('proxy_host' => "myserver.com", 'proxy_port' => 7676));`